# How to run code everyday with Parse for iOS?

Tags: parse-platform

Is there a way to run code everyday at a specific time with Parse for an iOS app? I would like to be able to send a push notification to specific users based on their settings and preferences found in various Parse data classes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about running code on the iOS everyday? The answer is no. Or are you talking about sending a push notification everyday?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about sending a push notification everyday to only certain users. I know I can't run code on the iOS side everyday due to the fact the user has to have the app open, but I'm hoping to send a push notification to certain users everyday.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#cloud-code-advanced-background-jobs

All you need is a background job. Then, you schedule it on the Parse dashboard and set a frequency.